# binding buttom to get strings from multiselect listbox in VBA

Tags: vba, excel, listbox

do anybody know how to get the strings from a multiselect listbox if the user click on a button in excel(VBA)?
And if i click on the button it take the strings into specific cells like D18,D19 and so on..

here is a little overview.
http://fs1.directupload.net/images/150625/o8xhqsll.jpg

Comment: Am I understanding you are trying to create a button then when pushed will loop through the items in a multi select list and any item selected it will write to a spread sheet?

Comment: @HolmesIV yes exactly, is it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the best bet is to take a look at this code, and try it out. Come back if you have more questions.

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    Me.ComboBox1.AddItem "a"
    Me.ComboBox1.AddItem "b"
    Me.ComboBox1.AddItem "c"
    Me.ComboBox1.AddItem "d"
End Sub

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Dim intComboItem As Integer

    For intComboItem = 0 To Me.ComboBox1.ListCount - 1
        If Me.ComboBox1.List(intComboItem).Selected = True then
             ''''Do something
        End If            
    Next
End Sub
```